# Simulating an Iscsi disk in a laptop( studying for VCP)

Tags: storage, vmware, esxi, iscsi

How do you simulate an iscsi disk. I tried many softwares but have been unable to add storage(iscsi disk) to my VMwork stations. Even after creating a virtual disk it is not able to recognize the disk in order to appoint it as an iscsi disk. I have two network cards and I have simulated 2 esxi 4.0 servers as well. Just cant get the storage sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try freenas.
http://www.freenas.org/

Install it on a VM and add iscsi connector to your nas. So you will have an iscsi disk for your vcp study.

Comment: Is there anything else other than freenas. Freenas is a load of problems getting it to work.